# Pretty printers for maps throwing a type error

Tags: c++, python, gdb, pretty-print

I've configured pretty printers using http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_inspect_the_contents_of_STL_containers.3F. It successfully works for vector and other containers. However I can't get to inspect maps as in the example below:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
map <int, string> mapIntToString;
map <int, int> mapInt2;
 mapIntToString.insert (map <int, string>::value_type (3, "Three"));
 mapInt2.insert (map <int, int>::value_type (3, 4));
 return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when printing using gdb:

```
(gdb) p mapInt2
$1 = std::map with 1 elementsTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myuser/opt/gdb_printers/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 422, in    children
rep_type = find_type(self.val.type, '_Rep_type')
File "/home/myuser/opt/gdb_printers/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 45, in    find_type
 raise ValueError, "Cannot find type %s::%s" % (str(orig), name)
ValueError: Cannot find type std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_Rep_type
```

Comment: I came as far as finding out that `_Rep_type` is [at least on some systems] a private typedef in std::map. perhap's that assumption is not always true. I suggest you notify the developers of pretty printers.

Answer (score 18):

What compiler (and which version) did you use to build your test source?

I am guessing it wasn't a recent version of `g++`. Here is what I get with `g++ 4.4.3-4ubuntu5`:

```
$ gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
(gdb) b 12   
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400de3: file t.cc, line 12.
(gdb) r

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.cc:12
12   return 0;
(gdb) p mapInt2
$1 = std::map with 1 elements = {[3] = 4}
```

**Update:**

> This is what I get for the version: g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

I see the problem. The instructions you've referenced are **incorrect**.

In particular, the instructions suggest: `svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python`, but the problem is that the python code reaches into `libstdc++` *internals*, and therefore *must* match these internals (this is the reason the pretty printers are part of GCC and not part of GDB, a fact bruce.banner complained about).

When you did a fresh `svn co ...`, you picked up a copy of python code that *no longer* matches your `libstdc++` internals, and that's what is causing you problems.

In particular, `svn log` shows that `find_type` was added here:

```
r183732 | tromey | 2012-01-30 08:25:11 -0800 (Mon, 30 Jan 2012) | 27 lines
```

That's *much* later than `gcc-4.4.3`. What you want to do then, is to get pretty printers that match *your* version of `libstdc++`, like so:

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gcc_4_4_3_release/libstdc++-v3/python
```

Except above command will not work, because gcc 4.4.3 predates the pretty printers.

No matter, the implementation of `std::map` (and much of the rest of STL internals) has not changed between 4.4.3 and 4.6, and this command *does* work:

```
 svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gcc-4_6-branch/libstdc++-v3/python
```

Comment: When I build gdb 7.3 from source on Ubuntu 7.3 it cannot print stl elements by default, I have to install the pretty printers.  Do you not feel this is a step backwards?

Comment: This is what I get for the version:
    g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

Comment: Thank you  employed russian! I had this problem at my work. We are using gcc/g++ that comes out of the box with RHEL5 and I was having difficulty following the instructions on setting up PrettyPrinters and I was getting the same std::map problem before your help!

Answer (score 0):

**On my system the type `_Rep_type` is not public type of `std::map`** (it's private typedef) so the script is trying to figure out a type of `<yourmap>._M_t` variable which is of type `_Rep_type` ...

I tried:

```
typedef std::map<int,int> map_t;
map_t m;
m.insert(map_t::value_type(3,4));
```

then in `gdb` I can print the key `3` like this (following the print function from the script I linked below):

```
p *(int*)(void*)(m._M_t._M_impl._M_header._M_left+1)
```

Where the `_M_t` in `std::map` is of `_Rb_tree` type but the type is not public in map (you can see that in your `map` header, specifically `<path/to/std-headers/dir/bits/stl_map.h` header file.

**Not sure if that helps one bit, basically there seems to be an issue with the pretty print python function that you are loading.**

I've just tried adding to `.gdbinit` stuff from [GNU GDB Debugger Command Cheat Sheet from yolinux.com](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html) (I googled for `gdb pretty print`) and with that I get reasonable output:

```
(gdb) pmap m int int
elem[0].left: $3 = 3
elem[0].right: $4 = 4
```

Comment: The fact that `_Rep_type` is a private typedef is irrelevant: GDB knows *all* types (and typedefs) when debug info is available. And the `pmap` is a really old and clunky way to print STL. Python pretty-printers are *much* nicer (when they work ;-)

Comment: Well, it seems to me that for some reason my GDB doesn't 'know' these types. I would prefer to stick with python pretty printers but don't know how to fix this problem. `_Rep_type` is private in stl_map.h, in my case.