# GDB printing STL data

Tags: python, c++, printing, stl, gdb

After following the instructions given on this site: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport 
GDB is still unable to print the contents of stl containers like vectors, other than printing out a huge amount of useless information. When GDB loads, I also get the following errors, which I think are related to the Python that I put into `~/.gdbinit`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Users/mayankp/gdb_printers/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 1247, in register_libstdcxx_printers
    gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(obj, libstdcxx_printer)
  File "/usr/local/share/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py", line 146, in register_pretty_printer
    printer.name)
RuntimeError: pretty-printer already registered: libstdc++-v6
/Users/mayankp/.gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
```

Answer (score 2):

> When GDB loads, I also get the following errors...

It looks like instructions you followed on https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport are invalid now. If you look at `svn log` you will see that registering of pretty printers was added in `__init__.py` recently:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r215726 | redi | 2014-09-30 18:33:27 +0300 (Вт., 30 сент. 2014) | 4 lines

2014-09-30  Siva Chandra Reddy  <sivachandra@google.com>

        * python/hook.in: Only import libstdcxx.v6.
        * python/libstdcxx/v6/__init__.py: Load printers and xmethods.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And therefore second registration throws error. You can remove it or comment out:

```
#register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
```

> GDB is still unable to print the contents of stl containers

You have probably mismatched pretty printers with your gcc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108404/72178 for details.

Answer (score 0):

From your traceback it seems that the `register_libstdcxx_printers()` call is failing because there already is such a pretty printer registered. To avoid that, you can wrap it in a `try..except` to make sure instructions in `.gdbinit` don't interfere with the launch of GDB if they fail:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/gdb_printers/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
try:
    register_libstdcxx_printers(None)
except:
    pass
end
```

(**Note**: You should usually *never* use a [bare `except` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except) without qualifying the type of exceptions you want to catch. This is a special case though, in startup configuration files like `.gdbinit`, `.pdbrc` or your `PYTHONSTARTUP` file you'll probably want to write defensive code like that).

But chances are this will only get rid of the ugly traceback for you, and printing of STL vectors still wont work. Because it seems there is already a pretty printer registered from somewhere else.

Make sure the path `/home/user/gdb_printers/python` actually matches the path where you checked out the module mentioned in the [STLSupport docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport).

Comment: I now get no error, but vectors and other stl data structures are still printed out as large amounts of useless information.